# Domain Name Expired, Will My Backorder Work?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

I'm interested in a domain name that expired August 9, 2012 and backordered it a few months ago. When I check the status of the domain name, it is listed as "autoRenewPeriod".

It has a new expiration date of August 9, 2013, but a Google search indicates that "autoRenewPeriod" means the registrar automatically renewed the domain but has not received payment yet.

Does anyone have experience with this? How long will it stay in "autoRenewPeriod" before being released by the registrar? Do I have a good chance of grabbing the domain name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally the autoRenewPeriod lasts up to 45 days. During this time the original registrant can renew the domain.

If, by the end of the autoRenewPeriod, the domain has not been renewed and you are the only person who has placed a back order then you should stand a good chance of getting the domain. If, however, there are others who have also back ordered the domain then it will enter an auction process where the highest bidder wins.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! The domain name entered a Pending Release auction at Namejet. So far, I'm the only bidder, so I should win it. :D Fingers crossed...

Comment: @TrentScott: I'm just wondering how did that go. Did you get the domain? I'm looking for a domain in a similar situation. Any tips?